# build - building chromium for android on mac m1

Tags: android, build, chromium, apple-m1

As per instructions given here [Checking out and building Chromium for Android](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/android_build_instructions.md), building the Android client on Windows or Mac is not supported and doesn't work.
Has anybody tried building it on mac m1? Is it really not possible?

The Mac M1 chip is ARM-based and most Android devices are ARM-based and given the toolchain, it should be possible. Please let me know.

After code checkout, when running -

```
build/install-build-deps.sh --android
```

getting error -

```
ERROR: lsb_release not found in $PATH
try: sudo apt-get install lsb-release
```

Clearly, lsb_release is available on Linux systems only. But is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, as per the documentation that is linked in the question:

> Building the Android client on Windows or Mac is not supported and
> doesn't work.

Even if there was a workaround and you managed to install all the dependencies, something else would probably break.

The best option is to install a linux machine (or actually - Ubuntu, as other distros might not work, as mentioned in the docs) and try there.

If you don't have the option to install a linux (virtual) machine, there is a workaroud for that - you can use docker. You can read more about it under the [linux instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md), linked in the docs.